# Type improperly determined

Tags: typescript

I have the following [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0Ainterface%20LoadingState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'loading'%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20DoneState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'done'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20(params%3A%20LoadingState%20%7C%20DoneState)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20state%20%7D%20%3D%20params%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(%20state%20%3D%3D%3D%20'loading')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20console.log('LoadingState')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20data%20%7D%20%3D%20params%0A%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A):

```
interface LoadingState {
    state: 'loading';
}
interface DoneState {
    state: 'done';
    data: any;
}

const test = (params: LoadingState | DoneState) => {
    const { state } = params;
    if ( state === 'loading') {
        return console.log('LoadingState');
    }
    const { data } = params
}
```

The last line of that code is throwing an error: `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'LoadingState | DoneState'.` I'm currently circumventing this with an explicit typecast:

```
const { data } = this.state as DoneState<T>;
```

The thing is, TS *knows* that the only valid option for state is "done", which means data *must* be defined. Am I missing something? Should I be defining my interface differently?

---

**EDIT**

My issue wasn't even something I asked. SORRY!! Turns out my problem was a little more complicated than I thought! I had something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20LoadingState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'init'%20%7C%20'loading'%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20DoneState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'done'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20(params%3A%20LoadingState%20%7C%20DoneState)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7Bstate%7D%20%3D%20params%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(%20state%20%3D%3D%3D%20'loading'%20%7C%7C%20state%20%3D%3D%3D%20'init')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20console.log('LoadingState')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7Bdata%7D%20%3D%20params%3B%0A%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20):

```
interface LoadingState {
    state: 'init' | 'loading';
}
interface DoneState {
    state: 'done';
    data: any;
}
const test = (params: LoadingState | DoneState) => {
    const {state} = params;
    if ( state === 'loading' || state === 'init') {
        return console.log('LoadingState');
    }
    const {data} = params;
}
```

To fix this, not only did I have to avoid destructuring of my params, but I had to add a new interface for `InitState` to split up the `state: 'init' | 'loading';` definition. Here's the working [result](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20InitState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'loading'%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20LoadingState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'init'%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20DoneState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'done'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20(params%3A%20InitState%20%7C%20LoadingState%20%7C%20DoneState)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20_state%20%3D%20params%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(_state.state%20%3D%3D%3D%20'loading'%20%7C%7C%20_state.state%20%3D%3D%3D%20'init')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20console.log('LoadingState')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20data%20%7D%20%3D%20_state%3B%0A%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The thing is, TS knows that the only valid option for state is "done"

Yes, but it does not make the connection back from the type of `state` variable to the type of `params` object where `state` came from. If you use `params.state` inside the `if` check it works as expected:

```
const test = (params: LoadingState | DoneState) => {
    if ( params.state === 'loading') {
        return console.log('LoadingState');
    }
    const { data } = params
}
```

Comment: You'r answer lead me in the right direction to narrow down my issue. I'll give you the _answer_ credit but i'll update my question with my findings.

Answer (score 1):

typescript actually don't know that you are testing what type is params inside that if condition. You can tell compiler explicitly that you are doing that with something called type guard: [ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20LoadingState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'loading'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20DoneState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'done'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20(params%3A%20LoadingState%20%7C%20DoneState)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20state%20%7D%20%3D%20params%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isDoneState(params))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20console.log('LoadingState')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20data%20%7D%20%3D%20params%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isDoneState(params%3A%20LoadingState%20%7C%20DoneState)%3A%20params%20is%20LoadingState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20params.state%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22loading%22%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Great answer, but it didn't solve my problem as my implementation code (not shown) uses generics which don't work with type guards.